# Change the_content() in Theme Thirteen

Tags: categories

I worked with site created on Theme Thirteen and theme uses
`<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?>`
to get post title, date, part of content and read-more link.
But now I need to show only post date and entire post content, but I can't find how to do that.  If I try to use `<?php the_content(); ?>` I get the same if I use `<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?>`
How to get post date and entire post content in template ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a read more tag in your posts, so you will need to remove them.

We can use the `the_content` filter to achieve that. We need to search and replace the `<!--more-->` tag with nothing.

You can try the following: (***NOTE:*** The following code is untested)

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function ( $content )
{
    return str_replace( '<!--more-->', '', $content );
}, 11 );
```

Comment: A "dirty"-but-easy tricks is to set `$GLOBALS['more'] = true`

Comment: @Heidel my pleasure. Enjoy :-)